# Way too much spaced between a table and a paragraph

Tags: spacing

I'm new to LaTex so I don't how to correct this problem.
The right part of the image shows the pdf and the left one shows the code.
As you can see, there is nothing more than words but the space in the pdf is way too much. Any idea on how to correct this?

[image]

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you use the `[H]` placement specifier, per chance?

Comment: do not post images of your code post a small test document that shows the problem. But here you have not shown the cause of the space, which is whatever code follows the code shown which is forcing the page to break with only that amount of text.

Comment: Which document class do you employ? Is the setting `\flushbottom` in force by any chance?

Comment: Helly everyone, thanks for your comments.
@Bernard Yes, I used [H] but then deleted it in order to see of that would correct the problem. It didn't.

Comment: Also try in your preamble the directive `\raggedbottom` (`\flushbottom` is the default).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, won't do it again. Is because these is no code before or after, there is only paragraphs with no code within.

Comment: @Mico I use this: \documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

Comment: @GermánDiegoGuisasolaPlejo if  the next line of your source is just text, then it should appear at the bottom of the output page you show. _Something_ you have not shown is forcing a page break at that point.